# Time Complexity of Sequential search

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I am trying to find the time complexity for selection sort which has the following equation 
 `T(n)=T(n-1)+O(n)`

First I supposed its T(n)=T(n-1)+n .. n is easier though..
Figured  `T(n-1) = T(n-2) + (n-1)`
and  `T(n-2) = T(n-3) + (n-2)` 
This makes `T(n) = (T(n-3) + (n-2)) + (n-1) + n` so its `T(n) = T(n-3) + 3n  - 3`.. 
K instead of (3) .. `T(n) = T(n-k) + kn - k` 
 
 and because n-k >= 0 .. ==> `n-k = 0` and `n=k` 
 
 Back to the eqaution its.. `T(n) = T(0)// which is C + n*n  - n` 
 which makes it `C + n^2 -n`.. so its O(n^2).. is what I did ryt??

Comment: Not quite. It's not `T(n-k) + kn - k`, but `T(n-k) + kn - sum_{1 to k-1} j`.

Comment: Can't get why?? it keeps getting K not the sum :s

Comment: `T(n-k) + (n-(k-1)) + (n-(k-2)) + ... + (n-1) + n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct. You are combining O(n) with O(n-1), O(n-2) ... and coming up with O(n^2). You can apply `O(n) + O(n-1) = O(n)`, but only finitely. In a series it is different.

```
T(n) = (0 to n)Σ O(n - i)
```

Ignore i inside O(), your result is O(n^2)

The recurrence relationship you gave `T(n)=T(n-1)+O(n)` is true for Selection Sort, which has overall time complexity as O(n^2). Check this [link](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~ola/ap/recurrence.html) to verify

Answer (score 0):

```
In selection sort:
```

In iteration i, we find the index min of smallest remaining entry.
And then swap a[i] and a[min].

As such the selection sort uses

`(n-1)+(n-2)+....+2+1+0 = (n-1)*(n-2)/2 = O(n*n) compares`

`and exactly n exchanges(swappings).`

**FROM ABOVE**

And from the recurrence relation given above

```
=> T(n) = T(n-1)+ O(n)
=> T(n) = T(n-1)+ cn, where c is some positive constant
=> T(n) = cn + T(n-2) + c(n-1)
=> T(n) = cn + c(n-1) +T(n-3)+ c(n-2)
```

And this goes on and we finally get

```
=> T(n) = cn + c(n-1) + c(n-2) + ...... c (total no of n terms)
=> T(n) = c(n*(n-1)/2)
=> T(n) = O(n*n)
```

**EDIT**

Its always better to replace theta(n) as cn, where c is some constant. Helps in visualizing the equation more easily.